# how do i create a border around iframe?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, border

I am trying to add a border to some conetnt on wordpress, and because i do not know how to add a css file i was trying to do everything in html (or at least i think is html). My knowledge of coding is left to my years in highschool.

This is the content around which i want to create a simple black border of 1 or 2 px:

```
<iframe src="https://link_to_my_file/file.pdf" style="width:1000px; height:300px;" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

however this does not work. So i tried this way:

```
<iframe src="https://link_to_my_file/file.pdf" style="width:1000px; height:300px;" frameborder="1"></iframe> <style> iframe.solid {border-style:solid} </style>
```

but this also did not work.

How do i put things in the proper way without necessarily using a separate css file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use inline HTML styling:

```
 <iframe src="https://link_to_my_file/file.pdf" 
    style="width:1000px; height:300px; border: 1px solid black;"></iframe>
```

Comment: thank you so much, you guys are amazing! Just a simple question: if i want to put 2 borders, one yellow and one blue, is it still possible to do it inline?

Comment: You can position a pseudo element such that it's either behind the element, and larger, making a border effect with it's own background. I suggest reading this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/

Comment: Hey Filip I cant seem to add a specific color: if i use this code it does nothing:     <iframe src="link_to_my_file.pdf" 
    style="width:1000px; height:300px; border: 8px;  border-color: 4593c6;"></iframe>

Comment: Try adding it in the border property. `border: 8px solid "colorhere"`

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The out put will not work in the snippet.
Attribute which are deprecated in HTML5 for `<iframe>`

**scrolling**

**frameborder**

**align**

**longdesc**

**marginwidth**

instead of using these as iframe inline attribute you can use it in css

**DEMO:**

```css
iframe{
border:4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=WyV_WvDBOY_E8wfHmba4Aw"></iframe>
```

visit this link for more info of deprecated attributes

https://html.com/tags/iframe/

Comment: To add on to this, frameborder is deprecated in HTML5. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_frameborder.asp

Comment: but it will provide by default border, i prefer css border if you want it

Answer (score 0):

Just add border declaration to style="" inside iframe tag.

```html
<iframe src="https://link_to_my_file/file.pdf" style="width:1000px; height:300px; border: 2px solid red"></iframe>
```

Comment: how do i modify the code to make the border of a specific color? (#4593c6)

Comment: `border: 2px solid #4593c6;`
check for reference here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp